# Load TensorFlow model from .pb file

Tags: python, file, tensorflow

**Background:** I have my TensorFlow model stored in a directory with the folders/files: assets, variables, and saved_model.pb. All I need to do with this model is make predictions (no training) so I do not need the assets and variables folders. The saved_model.pb file is much smaller than the variables folder and storage is extremely important to me.

**Question:** How could I load my TensorFlow model from the saved_model.pb file only (no variables or assets folders) in Tensorflow 2.3?

This is my file structure:

```
saved_models
├── model_1
|   ├── assets
|   |   └── (this is an empty folder)
|   ├── saved_model.pb
|   ├── variables
|   |   ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
|   |   └── variables.index
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `saved_model.pb` file only contains a description of the structure of the network. You need the variables as they contain the weights for each of the network layers, without them you would be doing prediction with a blank network.

Comment: So there is no way to decrease my file size? I must use everything?

Answer (score 1):

You could try saving the model in .h5 format. This just generates a single file . I am not sure if it is smaller than the .pb size but give it a try and find out. Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load)